# HERE Places (Search) API: Request parameter to specify the Places Category-Level to be included in API Response?

Tags: here-api

I am using the **HERE Places (Search) API** and my Responses include Places Categories on different Levels of the Places Category System (described here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/places-category-system.html)

**Example Responses:**

1. Places Category Response of 1st Request for GPS Pair 1: "Fast Food" -> 3rd Level Category
2. Places Category Response of 2nd Request for GPS Pair 2: "Eat and Drink" -> Top Level Category

**Problem:** I need all Places Categories in my responses on the same level for quantitative analysis (e.g. all on Top Level of Category System):

1. "Eat and Drink" -> Top Level Category
2. "Eat and Drink" -> Top Level Category

**Question:** Is there any **request parameter to specify the Places Category Level** to be included in the API response?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to filter the result by category number/id provided that only listed numbers are supported. Also you can use comma and specify more numbers.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/category-100-eat-drink.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/places-category-system.html

```
https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/browse?at=52.521,13.3807&cat=100-1000-0000&apikey={Your REST API_KEY}&cs=places
```

Comment: So far I have used API call `https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/around?in=52.521%2C-13.3807%3Br%3D800&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX`. Is it possible to request similar additional information to be included in the API response, e.g. "radius of place from requested GPS coord." or "place category number/name". Being interested in all type of places, I'ill include a list of categories in the API request and filter the the responded places by radius and definitely need the final place's category type/ number in the end for further analyses.